# Return nullable GCHandle from method

Tags: c#, .net

Want to do this, but GCHandle is not nullable. I need the GCHandle to retrieve the IntPtr associated to the buffer and later free it, so its not an option to just return IntPtr.

```
public GCHandle PacketToGCHandle(PacketAdmin packet)
{
    byte[] data;
    bool result;
    if ((data = PacketToByteData(packet)) != null)
    {
        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        return pinnedArray;
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
        report.BindReport(architecture.report);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Return `GCHandle?` instead, perhaps?

Comment: How can user know if GCHandle have an associated IntPtr?.

Comment: It's not up to the user to know it's up to how you are handling it in the program / application.. I am not understanding your comment ffenix

Comment: `GCHandle` may not be nullable, but `default (GCHandle)` behaves enough like `null` that one can use it in such situations. Just check `result.IsAllocated`, no need to wrap a `Nullable<>` around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it nullable:

```
public GCHandle? PacketToGCHandle(PacketAdmin packet)
```

Which is a short version of:

```
public Nullable<GCHandle> PacketToGCHandle(PacketAdmin packet)
```

It's value (if present) can be obtained through the `Value` property, and the `HasValue` property indicates whether it's `null` or not.